# Connecting to a Sybase Database using C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, odbc, sybase

How can I connect to a Sybase Database using C#.Net?
Do I need to install a specific dll or I should add something in the

```
using
```

section?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945501/sybase-ase-ado-net-2-0-provider

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do both.  You can either get providers from Sybase (my last experience was not entirely positive... their connector consisted of an unmanaged dll and a managed wrapper that was not portable across 32/64 bit machines), or use the ones from the Mono project.  I'm sure there are several other providers like DataDirect as well.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer provided so far is to download and install the ODBC drivers, then lookup connecting to ODBC in C#.